# Ajax call ASP.NET MVC + Jquery return "Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I´m trying to get data using Ajax, the Ajax call is working fine the problem is that it´s retuning "Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined". Here is the code:

Quarters Model

```
 public class Quarters
 {
    [Key]
    [Display(Name="Code")]
    public Int32 QuarterId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public String Description { get; set; }
 }
```

Months Model

```
public class Months
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    public Int32 MonthId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Quarters Quarter { get; set; }
    public Int32 QuarterId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
   public JsonResult Months(Quarters q) {
       var query = from c in _context.Months where c.QuarterId == q.QuarterId select c;
       return Json(query);
   }
```

JS

```
    $("select[name=quarters]").change(function () {
        var filterData = {
            QuarterId: $("select[name=quarters]").val(),
            Description: $("select[name=quarters]").text()
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: filterData,
            url: "/Folder/Controller/Months",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++)
                    console.log("Months: " + data[i].Description);
            }

        })
    })
```

Best Regards

Comment: what is `dados[i].Description`? dados is not defined in your JS code.
I guess it shoud be data[i].Description.

Comment: What is `dados`?  It's not defined in the code you have provided

Comment: `console.log("Months: " + data[i].Description);`

Comment: Sorry guys, I speak a different language, dados it means data in my country language. I already updated the code, I still with the same error...

Comment: Couple of things worth checking: do you have anywhere set SerializerSettings to ignore null values (NullValueHandling.Ignore) in your MVC project? Is it returning all other properties? do you have Description in database for the specified QuarterId for all the records?

Answer (score 0):

**data.length** returns the length of an array, but index start from 0, so you want to replace  `<=` with `<`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
   console.log("Months: " + data[i].Description);
```